# MacOSX changes my executable and it does not run the second time

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, gcc, wxwidgets

I compile my application on MacOSX 10.8.5 and create .app directory with all necessary stuff in it. It is wxWidgets and OpenGL app originally tested on Linux. When I run it, it just works perfectly fine. However, if I run it the second time it fails with the message:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /...path to the app directory.../
```

I copied the directory before the first run to run diff on them:

```
diff -ENwbur coupid.app coupid-orig.app
Binary files coupid.app/Contents/MacOS/coupid and coupid-orig.app/Contents/MacOS/coupid differ
```

`coupid` is the name of the application. That means that OS changed the binary!!! And after this change, the binary does not run with that strange error. Please, help, as I am totally unfamiliar with Mac but I have to make it Mac compatible.

I compiled the application with gcc compiler. That is the command line (for the main file only):

> g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/opt/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-2.9 -I/opt/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D_*WXMAC*_ -D_*WXOSX*_ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__ -I../../src -g -O2  -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE    -g -O2 -I/opt/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-2.9 -I/opt/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D_*WXMAC*_ -D_*WXOSX*_ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__ -MT coupid.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/coupid.Tpo -c -o coupid.o coupid.cc

this is the linking line:

> g++ -I../../src -g -O2  -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE    -g -O2 -I/opt/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-2.9 -I/opt/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D_*WXMAC*_ -D_*WXOSX*_ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__  -framework GLUT  -lhdf5 -llua  -o coupid coupid.o data.o model.o vars.o images.o frame.o dialog.o utility.o ../../src/lpio.o -lavcodec -lpthread -lz -lavutil -lpng -llua -lhdf5 -lm  -L/opt/local/lib   -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL -lwx_osx_cocoau_html-2.9 -lwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9 -lwx_baseu_net-2.9 -lwx_osx_cocoau_gl-2.9 -lwx_baseu-2.9

Again, my questions are:

1. Why OS changes the binary and what does it do with it?
2. Why it does not run it after that change
3. What can I do to avoid this behavior and fix the problem.

PS. I tested it on another MacBook Pro with my friend and he has exactly the same issue.
PPS. Another friend run it on Mac Air and the same issue! Very confusing.

PPPS. Info.plist file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
      <string>icon</string>
      <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
      <string>10K549</string>
      <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
      <string>English</string>
      <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
      <string>coupid</string>
      <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.yourcompany.coupid</string>
      <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
      <string>6.0</string>
      <key>CFBundleName</key>
      <string>coupid</string>
      <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
      <string>APPL</string>
      <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
      <string>1.0</string>
      <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
      <string>????</string>
      <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
      <string>1</string>
      <key>DTCompiler</key>
      <string></string>
      <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
      <string>10M2518</string>
      <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
      <string>PG</string>
      <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
      <string>10M2518</string>
      <key>DTSDKName</key>
      <string>macosx10.6</string>
      <key>DTXcode</key>
      <string>0400</string>
      <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
      <string>10M2518</string>
      <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
      <string>10.6</string>
      <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
      <string>MainMenu</string>
      <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
      <string>NSApplication</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: I believe this is related to how OS X handles running multiple instances of an application. If you launch your program from the terminal using `open -n <MyProgram.app>`, does it give any different behavior? Also, can you update your question text to include your `Info.plist` file?

Comment: Andon, well -n option did not change anything in behavior. I added Info.plist. Currently, I run the program with a little shell script that just copies the program code from previously saved original back to app folder. Yes, that is ugly, I know.

Comment: Have you tried just watching the syslog, something like opensnoop (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html), otool to look @ what changed, etc.? If the OS is modifying your binary, it's certainly not normal behavior.